# Adding styles to font awesome icons

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome

Below is what I tried.

```
<i class="fa fa-2x fa-border fa-user"></i>
```

This actually creates the icon, but i am not sure how to bring that `green color` over there on right corner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `:after` pseudo-element to add the triangle:

```
.fa-user {
    position: relative;
}
.fa-user:after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 12px 12px 0;
    border-color: transparent lightgreen transparent transparent;
}
```

See **[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/9PBFc/)**

Tip: Look up "CSS triangles" to get a grip on that